# Does Windows' tasklist tool consider a "K" to be 1000 or 1024 bytes?

Tags: windows

Nevermind what is "right". I only wonder what the tool `tasklist` thinks, because it doesn't support outputting raw bytes -- only "K", such as "12 345 K".

I've stared at its help output for quite some time now. Also searched online.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much all of Windows and most major operating systems work with base-2 multiples so 1024-byte "K's". You can prove this with [powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/1691920/how-do-i-get-the-raw-number-of-bytes-for-a-pid-on-windows-cli/1691928#1691928) where both KB and bytes can be shown under different output formats.

The only people who really use base-10 units for storage are the ones who have some vested interest in making their own numbers look better and everyone elses worse, just storage manufacturers.

Comment: "Storage manufacturers" – See the [drivemaker's kilobyte](https://xkcd.com/394/). :)