# Executing powershell script via cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

The powershell script I have works as expected when opened in powershell

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri host.com -Body "Param1=Value&Param2=Value&Param3=&Param4=Value" -Method POST
```

but when the same command is passed via cmd as

```
powershell.exe Invoke-WebRequest -Uri host.com -Body "Param1=Value&Param2=Value&Param3=&Param4=Value" -Method POST
```

it gives me these errors

```
'Param1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'Param2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'Param3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'Param4' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I know it's a syntax problem, but I'm not sure what needs to be changed exactly

EDIT:

```
powershell.exe Invoke-WebRequest -Uri host.com -Body 'Param1=Value&Param2=Value&Param3=&Param4=Value' -Method POST
```

That modification did nothing to change the results

Comment: Does this answer your question? [run powershell command from cmd](https://superuser.com/questions/1080239/run-powershell-command-from-cmd)

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the updated command that you ran that still failed based on the duplicate question?

Comment: Follow the syntax guidance as documented from the PowerShell CLI itself.  ***powershell /?***

Comment: This works to paste into a cmd window "  `powershell -command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri host.com -Body 'Param1=Value&Param2=Value&Param3=&Param4=Value' -Method POST"`

Comment: Shew, you said the pointer link did not work, but you are saying the line you posted did???  What you posted, syntactically, is the same as the pointer link. SO, is what you posted working or not? As per my ***powershell /?*** comment. Did you try the other examples that were provided via that? for example: ***powershell -Command "& {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri host.com -Body 'Param1=Value&Param2=Value&Param3=&Param4=Value' -Method POST}"***

Comment: Ah, now I see what went wrong, I didn't use -command, Nazard's code did work, thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that these are errors from **cmd**, not PowerShell. `&` characters split multiple commands in one line when not quoted or escaped (just like `;` in PowerShell). Maybe the body part is not wrapped in double quotation marks in your command, as you might actually run:

```
powershell Invoke-WebRequest -Uri host.com -Body 'Param1=Value&Param2=Value&Param3=&Param4=Value' -Method POST
powershell "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri host.com -Body "Param1=Value&Param2=Value&Param3=&Param4=Value" -Method POST"
```

Besides, you need to quote the body data using single quotation marks or triple quotes `"""`, because `powershell.exe` seems to remove double quotation marks for script passed by commands.
Therefore, the final command could be like (`-Command` option does not affect the result in this case, but adding it may help avoid ambiguity in some commands):

```
powershell [-Command] "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri host.com -Body 'Param1=Value&Param2=Value&Param3=&Param4=Value' -Method POST"
powershell [-Command] Invoke-WebRequest -Uri host.com -Body """Param1=Value&Param2=Value&Param3=&Param4=Value""" -Method POST
powershell [-Command] Invoke-WebRequest -Uri host.com -Body 'Param1=Value^&Param2=Value^&Param3=^&Param4=Value' -Method POST
```

Comment: '@Wilderness Ranger': As for this ***e (-Command option is not necessary...):***. There are parameters/switches to virtually all things PS, and many are positional/many are not, so, would be assumed, if not provided. It does not mean they are not used by PS under the covers. Yet, as a best practice, for maintenance, readability, and troubleshooting, it's best to use the full verboseness of PS, unless you are doing ad-hoc, thor-away code, CLI stuff. Without being explicit, PS will try and help, but it's best not to make any system guess for you. Give it specifics for clarity. Yet, choices...;-}