# Run PowerShell Command 'Start-Process' from Windows Shortcut

Tags: windows, powershell

It seems like this should be simple but I have tried for better than an hour to get it to work properly without success. **I have a working PowerShell command that I want to execute from a Windows shortcut.**

The command is:
`Start-Process -filepath "C:\Program Files\One Identity\Active Roles\7.3\Console\ActiveRoles.msc" -Verb RunAsUser`

This works as expected. It opens the GUI prompt to enter user/pass.

My expectation was that I could just create a shortcut with the target:
`powershell.exe -command '& {Start-Process -filepath "C:\Program Files\One Identity\Active Roles\7.3\Console\ActiveRoles.msc" -Verb RunAsUser}'`

That doesn't work. It flashes up but doesn't execute.

I tried running the command from PowerShell and it gave me `Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Identity\Active'` So I am now using an alternate path to avoid spaces:
`powershell.exe -command '& {Start-Process -filepath "C:\Progra~1\ONEIDE~1\ACTIVE~1\7.3\Console\ActiveRoles.msc" -Verb RunAsUser}'`

This still doesn't work. It won't run in PowerShell, so it won't work in a shortcut. It just gives me a new line in the PS window with no feedback.

Running just `Start-Process -filepath 'C:\Progra~1\ONEIDE~1\ACTIVE~1\7.3\Console\ActiveRoles.msc' -Verb RunAsUser` works fine.

I have tried a bunch of variations on this. I have tried with and without quotes, with and without spaces, with and without the &{}. I tried adding the single-line command to powershell script and calling that from a shortcut. This still doesn't work. The call executes without error but does not launch the .msc.

The goal of this is really to have a Windows shortcut that will launch the .msc with the -RunAsUser flag, but I am also interested more generally in how to get a pwershell command to run from a shortcut. Most of what I am finding in other posts is using bash commands with a commandline prompt, which isn't what I want. I feel like I must be missing something obvious here. This should be simple.

Comment: Could it be something with execution policy? Maybe set what you have to a .ps1 file and then call this from the shortcut:  `powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file "c:\temp\script.ps1"`

Comment: The problem is the spaces in the path. Use PowerShell ISE to determine what value exactly you are currently passing and update your question

Comment: You need use quotes like this `PowerShell -command "mycommand 'my path'"` - see https://superuser.com/questions/1080239/run-powershell-command-from-cmd/1080336#1080336

Comment: @Narzard I am sure it is firing. I can see the output of a write-output but it doesn't launch the .msc

Comment: @Ramhound I have tried without spaces as shown above without success.

Comment: @SimonS I tried reversing my usage of quotes as you suggested but still have no success getting the command to execute properly.

Comment: So, before messing with PS, are you saying, you've already created a desktop shortcut to ```ActiveRoles.msc```, which you can double-click to run successfully? Then, you opened that shortcut's properties and copied the target path string, and pasted that into PS console/ISE/VSCode and it won't run? Or, are you just manually typing this out? ***.msc*** files are executed by calling ```msc.exe (via cmd.exe)``` under the covers even when run from PS. Are you saying that only this ***msc*** file does not fire? Meaning, you've tried other default ***.msc*** file locations successfully?

Comment: @postanote I have a working shortcut with a target "C:\Program Files\One Identity\Active Roles\7.3\Console\ActiveRoles.msc" which works fine, but does not prompt for creds. If I drop it in powershell with dot execution it runs fine .`'C:\Program Files\One Identity\Active Roles\7.3\Console\ActiveRoles.msc'` The goal is to use -Verb RunAsUser so every time the shortcut is run it prompts for user creds, This works from PS with `Start-Process -filepath 'C:\Progra~1\ONEIDE~1\ACTIVE~1\7.3\Console\ActiveRoles.msc' -Verb RunAsUser` but not from a shortcut

Comment: You should not expect this to work from a shortcut as written. Start-Process is a PS cmdlet, which can only be run when in a PS session.

Answer (score 1):

Point of note. As per the `Start-Process` help docs.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.2
>
> -Verb Specifies a verb to use when this cmdlet starts the process. The verbs that are available are determined by the filename extension of
> the file that runs in the process.
>
> The following table shows the verbs for some common process file
> types.

- File type    Verbs
- ***.cmd***   Edit, Open, Print, RunAs, ***RunAsUser***
- .exe Open, RunAs, RunAsUser
- .txt Open, Print, PrintTo
- .wav Open, Play

***Note that .msc is not on the list.***

Windows knows what to do with shortcuts with targets like this...

```
'C:\Program Files\One Identity\Active Roles\7.3\Console\ActiveRoles.msc'
```

... files with .msc tells Windows to launch msc.exe to execute .msc files because that executable is how Windows has it mapped.

Windows has no idea what to do with this...

```
Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\One Identity\Active Roles\7.3\Console\ActiveRoles.msc'
```

... because `Start-Process`, is not an executable, it is only viable in a running/instantiated PowerShell session.

You have to do the below, for what you are after in a shortcut.

```
powershell "Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\One Identity\Active Roles\7.3\Console\ActiveRoles.msc'"
```

PowerShell must first be launched, to run PS cmdlets, then the path to anything else you want that cmdlet to do.

Demo:
[image]

Comment: Have you been able to get this to work using -Verb RunAsUser? The goal is to have a shortcut that opens the user credentials dialog. One of the first things I tried was a shortcut calling powershell with the command `powershell "Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\One Identity\Active Roles\7.3\Console\ActiveRoles.msc' -Verb RunAsUser"` This doesn't work for me.

Comment: Though the docs for Start-Process don't explicitly list .msc, the command `Start-Process -filepath "C:\Program Files\One Identity\Active Roles\7.3\Console\ActiveRoles.msc" -Verb RunAsUser` works as expected from a PowerShell window. I am trying to produce this result from a shortcut.